# Why doesn't (can't) the OS translate C code directly into machine language instead first translating it into assembly language?

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction

As far as I've understood, when a program (written in C for example) is compiled, it is first translated into assembly language and then into machine language. Why can't (isn't) the "assembly language step" be skipped?

Comment: What benefit would it have? What problem would that solve? (And I'm sure some compilers go to machine code directly. The OS has nothing to do with any of that.)

Comment: So you're saying that behind C code there's no assembly language? Then how come is runs faster that C?

Comment: Plenty of compilers skip a textual assembly stage..

Comment: Neither C nor assembly language is *executed*. Both must be translated to machine code before they can be executed. Translating C directly to machine code vs. translating to assembly language which is then translated to machine code should have no impact on execution speed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easier for the compiler developers.

It is possible to write a compiler that reads C and writes object code. However, this requires the compiler writer to write all the computations that encode instructions. Instruction encodings are intricate on some machines. Additionally, there are fields to fill in that depend on other interactions, such as how far away a branch target is, which depends on what instructions are between the branch and the target.

Additionally, part of the way a compiler is written is with patterns that say things like “To increment an object x, issue an increment instruction.” In order to write object code directly, you have to encode all the instructions you want to write into those patterns. That means your patterns must have some sort of language for describing instructions.

Well, we already have a language for that: assembly language. So it is simply easier to write your patterns in ways like “To increment an object x, issue `inc x`.”

Modern compilers have many layers. There is a front end that reads C text (or other languages) and turns it into a language internal to the compiler. There is an optimizer that operates on the internal language (or a representation of it) and tries to improve the code. There is a back end that turns the internal language into assembly language. There is an assembler that turns the assembly into object code. And there is a linker that links object code into an executable file.

As with many complex tasks, it is simply easier for human minds to work with a complex task when it is separated into nice pieces. This reduces bugs and improves the time it takes to work with software. It also makes software flexible, because we can change the front end to support a new language (e.g., Java instead of C) or change the back end to support a new processor (change from Intel assembly to PowerPC assembly). And changing one optimizer improves all the compilers, for Java and C and Intel and PowerPC.

The gcc command that we use to compile is actually just a driver that calls other programs that perform the front-end processing, the optimization, the assembly, and the linking. You can also call most of these phases separately, or use a switch to tell gcc to show you the commands it is using.

Additionally, GCC has a feature that allows developers to insert assembly language directly intermixed with the C code. This compels GCC to include an assembler.

Comment: I think it is more for historic reasons in the open source C compilers, and maybe a bit laziness (to have both a decent machinecode writer for speed and a separate textual assembler writer for easier inspection of output).

Answer (score 6):

Your understanding is wrong, compilers do not necessarily translate C code into assembler. They usually perform several phases and have internal representations, but this doesn't necessarily resemble to a human readable assembler.

Here, I found a nice introduction for [LLVM](http://www.aosabook.org/en/llvm.html). LLVM is the compiler toolkit that is used for clang.

Answer (score 2):

The operating system does not do anything like that. This is the job of the compiler. And in fact, many *do* directly emit object files - you have to explicitly ask them to emit assembly code. Others choose not to because emitting a fully-featured object file requires expert knowledge about the various formats which exist for this. Assemblers have various convenience features which make the job easier, can (sometimes?) target multiple object file formats without changes in the assembly code. Also, it is a very useful feature to emit annotated assembly code, so not having a separate code generator only for direct object file emission saves you time without any restrictions (except needing an assembler), which makes it an attractive option when you have limited resources.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the compiler; there is no actual need for the assembly code.

Maybe the authors of whatever compiler you are talking about (GNU-CC?) considered it slightly easier for themselves if they didn't have to resolve certain things like branches themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Assembly code is purely a convenient, somewhat-human-readable representation of the machine code **and** the symbolic references and relocations needed by the linker when putting together the output of different translation units. Without an intermediate assembly-language step, the compiler would also be responsible for generating the relocations in the form the linker needs, which is doable, but painful. Since an assembler with this capability already exists for processing hand-written assembly code, it makes sense to use it.

Answer (score 1):

There is usually no assembler stage. MSVC (cl.exe) and GCC produce machine code (.obj, .o) right away.

Comment: Actually, GCC always produces the assembly, but it may be present only in memory (piped into the assembler instead of using temporary files). Compile a file with `-v` and you'll see that it does call `as`.

Answer (score 1):

A cross compiler can directly generate the machine code without the help of the OS where that cross compiler is installed.

For example, tornado package installed in windows can generate machine code for vxworks.